# setting user alias as message recipient

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, user and treating (which you can think of as a message).

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    has_many :sent_treatings, :foreign_key => "requestor_id", :class_name => "Treating", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :received_treatings, :foreign_key => "requestee_id", :class_name => "Treating", dependent: :destroy

end
```

Treating:

```
class Treating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :intro, :proposed_date, :proposed_location

  validates :intro, presence: true, length: { maximum: 190 }
  validates :requestor_id, presence: true
  validates :requestee_id, presence: true

    belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :requestee, class_name: "User"

    default_scope order: 'treatings.created_at DESC'

end
```

I'm having trouble in my treatings controller setting 'requestee':

```
class TreatingsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user

    def create
        requestee = ?
        requestor = current_user
        @received_treating = requestee.received_treatings.build(params[:treating])
        @received_treating.requestor = requestor

        if @received_treating.save
            flash[:success] = "Treating request sent!"
            redirect_to users_path
        else
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    end
end
```

The question mark I tried to replace with: User.find(params[:id]), hoping that the user in the current 'users/show' view would be found, but I get this error:

Couldn't find User without an ID

I also tried User.find(params[:treating][:requestee_id]), but this didn't work either. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

views/shared/_treating_form.html.erb (this references @received_treating in the users controller, show action):

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :intro, placeholder: "Write your introduction here..." %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

EDIT: adding other user profile page:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= gravatar_for @user %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
        <% if signed_in? %>
            <section>
                    <%= render 'shared/treating_form' %>
            </section>
        <% end %>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <% if @user.received_treatings.any? %>
        <h3>Treating requests (<%= @user.received_treatings.count %> received)</h3>
        <ol class="treatings">
            <%= render @received_treatings %>
        </ol>
            <%= will_paginate @received_treatings %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the form that makes that request would help to see what is going on

Comment: thanks ismaelga, i added the _treating_form.html.erb file. would love to hear what you think

Comment: where you select the user to be the requestee? Or how you know who is the requestee for the treating? That form is beeing rendered in the show view of the supposed requestee user?

Comment: the treating message form will appear on another user's profile page, i.e. the views/users/show.html.erb page (i just added above). so i want the requestee to be that user whose profile page is currently being viewed by the current_user (requestor is the current_user). thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think just adding `@user.id` in a hidden_field would work.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :requestee_id, :input_html => { :value => @user.id }
<div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :intro, placeholder: "Write your introduction here..." %>
</div>

<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

You could also populate the field doing

```
<%= form_for @user.received_treatings.build do %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :requestee_id %>
  ....
```

On the controller just do

```
@received_treating = current_user.sent_treatings.build params[:treating]
```

I have some doubts if this works but I think it should help you out.

Comment: i'm pretty sure i need to declare 'requestee' in my treatings controller, b/c if i don't i get: undefined local variable or method `requestee' for #<TreatingsController:0x00000102479a48>

Comment: see where you are calling it. If you need to render it in the view just do `@received_treating.requestee`, there is no need to have that extra variable. One thing you might need to do is add `attr_accessible :requestee_id` in your treeting model

Comment: i think i need to keep requestee_id inaccessible for security reasons, no?

Comment: I dunno. I think there are no problems on doing so. You should protect attributes that user should not be able to define, like account balance for example. requestee_id is an attribute that the user defines right? At least this is how I think it's suppose to be. But you should search about it, don't trust 100% on what I say :p There should be some questions about it here in SO.

Comment: Also I never done any project on Rails to go live. So I never tough to much about security issues like this one.